# Views: Get nodes of last added Node Reference

Tags: nodes, views

I'm working on a online magazine in drupal.
I have one content type called *issue* with one field, the title field.
And I have a content type called *article* the default drupal content type with a *node reference* field linking to issue.

I first make an *issue* called 'issue 01'. Then I start making some articles linked to 'issue 1' via the *node reference* field.

Then I make a second *issue* called 'issue 02'. And make some articles to go with this issue.

Now I want to make a view to show on the homepage showing all articles of the last added *issue* so for 'issue 02'. And when I would add a new *issue* called 'issue 03' the home page should automatically show the articles from this issue.

I'm trying to make this work via the relationship option and the contextual filter option in Views, the relationship is made. And the view is showing all articles. Now I want it to be filtered to showing articles of the last *issue* only so I thought about using the contextual filter but I can't find out a way to get, for instance, the NID of the last added *issue*.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by the date DESC and restrict the displayed items to 1 through your pager options.

[image: Only display most recent]

Comment: Okay, but this is not what I ment. I know these options. But my view at this moment outputs all articles of all issues and I want it to show all articles of the most recent issue. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Offhand without changing what you have you could do a hook_query_alter and add a condition for post date === MAX(post date). But you could also set up your view a little differently. Something like have a block (or page) to display your issues that only shows 1 and then an attachment that shares exposed and contextual filters, same idea as the glossary view example.

Comment: Iv'e had issues with the attachment actually reading the contextual filters when using a block but you might not need it this way.

Comment: Okay thanks, I don't really understand what you mean by the attachment. I tried itwith the PHP code option in the contextual filter. I just search the database for the last added issue and use this NID to filter the content. I got it to work now but I'm wondering if it's the right way to do it.

Comment: At the end of the 'Displays' list in your view there is an `+Add` button. One of the selections here is 'attachment'. You can use these by attaching them to other displays. They can help add functionality to your view.